# Redirecting HTTP/HTTPS request to a different URL destination using Javascript/Vue/NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, redirect

Looking for some advice as I'm not clear on how to approach this problem based on my searches.

I have a javascript project built on vue/npm. I have to redirect an HTTP request (a .js url) to a different destination while the page loads. Basically, while the page loads URL1 needs to be treated as a 302 and point to URL2 and return OK 200.

Anyone can advise me on it? Maybe an NPM package that already does something like it?

Thank you.

Comment: The server has no knowledge about the state of a webpage, if it's loading or already finished. It just handles isolated http requests. Especially what happens if the page has already finished loading from one client, but is still loading on another one? What should the serve return? And what would be the use case of such a scenario?

Comment: If the question is "how to do a redirect" we would need to know what is running on your server, because in my understanding Vue is a clientside framework ...

Comment: @derpirscher Im going to execute the function via javascript while the page loads. What I'm looking to do is to intercept URL1 network request coming from the server response as the page renders and redirect it to URL2. That's the main idea, so I'm looking for options on how to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean by that. You cannot "intercept" responses from the server and redirect them in JavaScript what would be the practical use case of such an operation?

Comment: I do such operation with this chrome extension tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en

Comment: For example, if there is a minified .js file (URL1) that loads on the webpage, I can redirect the URL to the unminified.js version from a different URL(URL2).

Comment: Yeah, but the major difference is, that is *the browser* (or at least a browser extension) intercepting that request and not the *webpage*